# how to access player prefab in endless runner game?

Tags: unity, c#, unity-ads

I am working on an endless runner.

The player is a prefab.
After player died, when user press watch ad, the game should continue and player should respawn where he died previously.

```
public void showAd()
{

    game_ = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Game_manager>();
    game_.gameOn = true;
  Instantiate(playerPrefab, new Vector3(0, -0.337f,game_.spawnPos+10), Quaternion.identity);
    Debug.Log("ad is here");

}
```

Comment: Do you need general information on the basics of how [ad integration works in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAds.html)? Or do you just need a way to pause the game until the ad is over?

Comment: @philipp just need a way to pause or resume the game untill.the ad is over